# What is a good term for "common people" in an academic thesis?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

In an academic thesis, what is a good word to use for "common people" that is not condescending?

I am using the term in opposition to "pundits" and "experts."

I need a formal term appropriate for an academic thesis.

Comment: The ***laity***.

Comment: Answers given at [What do you call a generic person?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208192/what-do-you-call-a-generic-person); 'the average person' and 'the man in the street' seem appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, but I was looking for something more formal.

Comment: 'The average man' is probably cross-register.

Comment: Laity has religious connotations.  I wouldn't use it in a secular context.